# Using Charles to get full paths of endpoints used by app downloaded from App Store

Tags: ios, security, networking, charles-proxy

I have an app I have downloaded from the App Store and I want to get access to the raw endpoints it is using so I can interact with the data in a more accessible format (e.g., JSON) instead of through the app GUI.

I am using Charles and routing my iOS traffic through my MacBook as a proxy. However, when I interact with the app I see only the domain; the `path` is empty. I've also downloaded SSL certs onto both my iOS device and MacBook from Charles and given them permissions; however, I still see a red `X` on the left-hand side (see screenshot below). I don't know if that's the reason I can't see the path though. [image: Charles screenshot]

Comment: Look like you forgot to Trust the Certificate in your iOS Devices. You can find it in Setting app > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings and switch ON the certificte. Detailed Guideline here: https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-device#ios-setup-guide

Comment: @NghiaTran actually, oddly, I did trust the certificate, which is what confused me significantly.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug from Charles Or your device is still caching the old certificate. Restart both might resolve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do it by proxying through my macbook, but I was able to do it on the iOS Charles app ($9 download).